# PHP SimpleXML create form based on xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have xml formatted as this (example of one node):

```
<company key="Nameofcompany" enabled="true">
    <title>Nameofcompany</title>
    <phone type="domestic" href="tel:02480">02480</phone>
    <phone type="international" href="tel:+33333333">+33 33 3333</phone>
    <email href="mailto:mail@example.com" />
    <homepage href="http://www.example.com" />
    <webcompanyURL href="http://m.example.com/sbv" />
    <balanceURL href="http://m.example.com/sbv/balance" />
    <youtube href="http://www.youtube.com/account">YouTube</youtube>
    <facebook href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Company/45454545?sk=wall" />
    <blog href="http://www.example.com/" />
    <opening-hours>
        <line>08.15 - 16.00 (Summer 08.15-15.30)</line>
    </opening-hours>
    <services>
        <phone-company type="domestic" href="tel:02480">02480</phone-bank>
        <disable-card type="domestic" href="tel:02222">02222</disable-card>
        <disable-card type="international" href="tel:+4702222">+47 02222</disable-card>
        <disable-card type="sms" href="sms:02222?text=OLALA">02222</disable-card>
        <disable-card type="email" href="mailto:02222@example.com?subject=Olala&amp;body=Phone:+">02222@example.com</disable-card>
        <disable-card type="international" href="tel:+333333333">+33 3333333</disable-card>
        <report-accident type="domestic" href="tel:02300">02300</report-accident>
        <report-accident type="international" href="tel:+33 33 33 33 33">+33 33 33 33 33</report-accident>
    </services>
</bank>
```

I need to create HTML form to edit and create nodes and save it in this xml file. How to implement such functionality?

Comment: By the way, your XML is invalid - you've opened with `<company>` but closed with `</bank>` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off with constructing your HTML form, and retrieving the elements in a POST operation - that is just the same as if you were saving the data to the database.

Then you need to decide how you wish to manipulate your XML document - in PHP there are [quite a few](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

My preferred approach is SimpleXML, but use whatever you prefer. Create your document like this:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<company key="' . $key . '" enabled="true"/>');
$doc->addChild('title', $nameOfCompany);
$hours = $doc->addChild('opening-hours');
$hours->addChild('line', $lineStr);
```

Or if you wish to create the document all in one go, you can just create it as a string, and supply it to the constructor to SimpleXMLElement.

Once you get a bit more proficient with SimpleXMLElement, bear in mind you can extend it and/or do all sorts of interesting things with it, like XPath queries. For example, [here](https://github.com/halfer/Meshing/blob/master/lib/Meshing/Schema/Element.php) is something I am working on atm.

Hope that helps!